# How to get the "real" difference of lines when comparing two files or how to substract lines form A to lines of B and vv. very fast as bash oneliner?

Tags: bash, join, diff, difference, comm

Suppose you have two large files where each line from file A and B start with the same unique sequence but may differ afterwards, like in

```
A:
a#123
b#foo
c#
d#1a
.
.
.
```

and

```
B:
a#
b#foo
c#234
d#1a
.
.
.
```

To get the "real" difference, so NOT the lines which are different,
I can use an easy loop which returns the difference, like in

```
Difference:
123

234

.
.
.
```

My question is now, if there is a bash "oneliner" or a tool/combination in general in Linux which can handle the same but faster? I have tried comm, diff, join and grep but it seems I am not capable to get more than a lines-which-are-different result. I'm not familiar with awk, which is maybe another candidate.

Any good hints and ideas are very welcome. Thx!

Comment: What should the output look like when you have files with: `e#foo` and `e#bar` ?

Comment: Not the case. But assume to use always the whole line from file A as difference in that case.

Comment: And what about these blank lines, do they have to be there if the input line is the same in both files?

Comment: Yes, because that's the difference. Thx for clarifing.